# Make Angular Bootstrap Typeahead go up

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

The typeahead suggestion box goes down - its a drop down list. How can I make it go up so that the base of the suggestions box is at the top of the text field?

Like this for example...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this by removing the following from the template:

```
top: position.top+'px',
```

This from my CSS:

```
top: 100%;
```

And adding the following to the CSS:

```
bottom: 38px;
```

Where 38px is the height of the text box. Unfortunately the `top` declarations had to be removed because there's no way as far as I know to unset `top` without using script and it takes precedence over `bottom`.

I own the CSS and I can put the template in a separate file that overrides the default so I won't lose my changes.